# value of the option selected not passing in react

Tags: reactjs

Trying to get a response when clicking and store the selected option from the selected value genre, not sure how to add a select new state variable or a post method. When the option is clicked the click handler is not called with the selected options so that we can add it to the state. My genre is also seen as undefined when I don't click on the the text type.

Feedback.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { ToastContainer, toast } from "react-toastify";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.min.css";
import Layout from "./Layout";


const Feedback = () => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    name: "",
    artist: "",
    songTitle: "",
    email: "",
    message: "",
    phone: "",
    genre: "",
    uploadedFiles: [],
    buttonText: "Submit",
    uploadPhotosButtonText: "Upload files",
  });

  // destructure state variables
  const {
    name,
    artist,
    songTitle,
    label,
    email,
    message,
    phone,
    genre,
    uploadedFiles,
    buttonText,
    uploadPhotosButtonText,
  } = values;
  // destructure env variables
  const {
    REACT_APP_API,
    REACT_APP_CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME,
    REACT_APP_CLOUDINARY_UPLOAD_SECRET,
  } = process.env;

  // event handler
  const handleChange = (name) => (event) => {
    setValues({ ...values, [name]: event.target.value });
  };

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setValues({ ...values, buttonText: "...sending" });
    // send to backend for email
    console.table({ name, email, phone, message, uploadedFiles, genre });
    axios({
      method: "POST",
      url: `${REACT_APP_API}/feedback`,
      data: {
        name,
        artist,
        songTitle,
        label,
        email,
        genre,
        phone,
        message,
        uploadedFiles,
      },
    })
      .then((response) => {
        // console.log('feedback submit response', response);
        if (response.data.success) toast.success("Thanks for your feedback");
        setValues({
          ...values,
          name: "",
          artist: "",
          songTitle: "",
          label: "",
          phone: "",
          email: "",
          genre: "",
          message: "",
          uploadedFiles: [],
          buttonText: "Submitted",
          uploadPhotosButtonText: "Uploaded",
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // console.log('feedback submit error', error.response);
        if (error.response.data.error) toast.error("Failed! Try again!");
      });
  };
  function onChangeInput(value) {
    console.log(value);
  }
  const uploadWidget = () => {
    window.cloudinary.openUploadWidget(
      {
        cloud_name: REACT_APP_CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME,
        upload_preset: REACT_APP_CLOUDINARY_UPLOAD_SECRET,
        tags: ["ebooks"],
      },
      function (error, result) {
        // console.log(result);
        setValues({
          ...values,
          uploadedFiles: result,
          uploadPhotosButtonText: `${
            result ? result.length : 0
          } Photos uploaded`,
        });
      }
    );
  };

  const feedbackForm = () => (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div className="form-group">
        <button
          onClick={() => uploadWidget()}
          className="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-block p-5"
        >
          {uploadPhotosButtonText}
        </button>
      </div>

      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label className="text-muted">Description</label>
          <textarea
            onChange={handleChange("message")}
            type="text"
            className="form-control"
            value={message}
            required
          ></textarea>
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label className="text-muted">Your Name</label>
          <input
            className="form-control"
            type="text"
            onChange={handleChange("name")}
            value={name}
            required
          />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label className="text-muted">Your Email</label>
          <input
            className="form-control"
            type="email"
            onChange={handleChange("email")}
            value={email}
            required
          />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label className="text-muted">Your Phone</label>
          <input
            className="form-control"
            type="number"
            onChange={handleChange("phone")}
            value={phone}
            required
          />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label className="text-muted">Artist Name</label>
          <input
            className="form-control"
            type="text"
            onChange={handleChange("artist")}
            value={artist}
            required
          />
        </div>

        <div className="form-group">
          <label className="text-muted">Song Title</label>
          <input
            className="form-control"
            type="text"
            onChange={handleChange("songTitle")}
            value={songTitle}
            required
          />
        </div>

        <div className="form-group">
          <label className="text-muted">Record Label Name</label>
          <input
            className="form-control"
            type="text"
            onChange={handleChange("label")}
            value={label}
          />
        </div>


        <div className="form-group">
          <label className="text-muted">Music Genre:</label>
          <select
            className="form-control"
            value={genre}
            type="select"
            onChange={handleChange("genre")}
          >
            <option value="steak">Steak</option>
            <option value="sandwich">Sandwich</option>
            <option value="dumpling">Dumpling</option>
          </select>
        </div>

        <button className="btn btn-outline-primary btn-block">
          {buttonText}
        </button>
      </form>
    </React.Fragment>
  );

  return (
    <Layout>
      <ToastContainer />
      <div className="container text-center">
        <h1 className="p-5">Feedback Online</h1>
      </div>
      <div className="container col-md-8 offset-md-2">{feedbackForm()}</div>
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default Feedback;
```

Comment: Are you saying the onChange handler returned by handleChange('genre') isn't getting invoked when you choose an option from the select?

Comment: yes, select option will not pass when i click.